# When to constrain template parameter types to concrete classes

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a function template that can be defined for all types `Stream`, e.g.

```
template<typename Stream>
Stream& foo(Stream& stream)
{
    return stream;
}
```

are there any advantages to restricting the type to a concrete class, e.g.

```
template<typename CharT, Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& foo(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& stream)
{
    return stream;
}
```

or should a function / class template as a rule of thumb always be as generic as possible, even when you have specific types in mind?

Comment: If your template function only works under some constraints put that in the documentation. One might provide a `istream`-like class, which could work in your original case but doesn't work in your more explicit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have no constraints or concepts yet in current C++, so your former template interface is more general than needed, because it accepts also types that are not streams in its interface. This will cause easy ambiguities when you call your function template and it is overloaded.

So make your function template as generic as possible, but not more general than needed. Your effort is best put into something else in that case.

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to create a function that works on both lvalues and rvalues, do I have any option other than changing the signature of the first to `Stream&&`? Would this be a valid case for a generic type?

Comment: @user657267 you can write a `is_stream` traits class, then take `Stream&&` and use SFINAE to enforce `is_stream<std::decay<Stream>::type>::value`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ambiguity. It can be avoided using SFINAE with `enable_if` but this is far from easy to write (not mentioning reading, debugging, maintaining and reviewing; it's just not fun to work with). Concepts will help us in a future version of C++, where you can restrict the template types.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of templates over restricting the type is that your function works if the given type supports what your function needs to do with the parameter, no more. This is also called "duck typing".

This is very nice in particular for arithmetic calculations, which then automagically work for all types which implement arithmetic operators.

On the other hand, a good example where you don't want this is (i.e. an advantage of strict types) when you expect a specific behavior of the type which can't be expressed in "duck typing", for example if your functions requires `a += b` to be the same as `a = a + b` (although this *should* always hold if you overload operators), or a specific (and wanted) side effect takes place when calling a function on the type. However, such "requirements" can (and are typically) be expressed in the documentation (comments) of your function, for example ("`T::size()` is expected to return the number of ...").

A general rule of thumb is: Use a specific type if you know in advance which types you want to call that function on, for example if you already have an abstract super class. Use templates if you want the set of types to be more "unlimited".